# How to tell mvn to use local folder to solve Local Dependency issue for zxing's Android project

Tags: android, maven, zxing

I downloaded zxing and tried to build it locally with mvn.

I got some problem, when I try to build android project (to make it a jar other than apk file), I got this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
[INFO] Building Android Barcode Scanner app 4.7.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.zxing:android-core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.352 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-27T13:32:25+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/36M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project android: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google.zxing:android:jar:4.7.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT, com.google.zxing:android-core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

I put android-core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.JAR AND core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.JAR into the libs folder of android project, but it doesn't help at all.

what I am doing wrong? The pom file under android folder is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>android-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>(i changed from apk to jar as I want to build it as a jar other than apk)

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>zxing-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <name>ZXing Android Core</name>
  <description>Code common to Android applications</description>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Maven question. You have downloaded source code for `master`, so points to `SNAPSHOT` builds. If you really want to use that, you need to `mvn install` to create snapshot artifacts locally. Here you just went straight to `android/` and built it, but that won't work. Just build everything from the top level and it will work.

This is described at https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing except that if you are building snapshots off `master` you need to `mvn install` not `mvn package`.